# Which aspect of simple system call (getTimeOfDay) to Linux Kernel is most expensive in terms of required CPU time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, time, system-calls

Is it entering and exiting the Kernel? or executing the actual system routine to determine the time, or is it making the function call, or is it storing the system call's returned value?

Comment: Definitely "entering and exiting the Kernel" is the expensive bit - in particular, saving and restoring the process context.

Comment: On many architectures, `gettimeofday` is handled by the [vDSO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) and *doesn’t* need to switch to kernel mode.